# Eclipse DTP does not show nvarchar on SQL server

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, nvarchar, eclipse-dtp

In latest Eclipse (Mars), data sources explorer will not show NVARCHAR types on MS SQL Server data connections. This is true for previous versions as well, along with open-source derivatives such as STS. However, commercial tools such as Rational Application Developer show the types utilizing the same data source.

The NVARCHAR type shows up correctly on other databases (Oracle).

How can I get Eclipse (DTP) to properly show NVARCHAR utilizing data sources explorer? We utilize this with ORM mapping, so types are important when reverse-engineering.

Comment: I'm also confirming this continues to happen in Eclipse Neon. I've tried many combinations of Generic JDBC/SQL Server drivers. Other posts on SO seem to indicate the problem is at the DTP layer, however I'm using the latest DTP components that are available with Neon.